# Flask Login: TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported

Tags: flask, uwsgi, flask-login

I am running flask, pymongo and flask-login as a stack.

My flask app is running fine locally, but once I deploy it with uwsgi on nginx, I get a strange unicode error from flask_login extension.

**In short:**

```
TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported
```

**Traceback:**

```
[pid: 21753|app: 0|req: 5/5] 84.207.253.34 () {38 vars in 600 bytes} [Thu Jun 13 16:51:08 2013] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 4 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 0 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/myproject/myproject-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/myproject/myproject-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/myproject/myproject-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/myproject/myproject-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/myproject/myproject-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/myproject/myproject-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/myproject/myproject-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1473, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.preprocess_request()
  File "/myproject/myproject-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1666, in preprocess_request
    rv = func()
  File "/myproject/myproject-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 311, in _load_user
    deleted = self._session_protection()
  File "/myproject/myproject-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 325, in _session_protection
    ident = _create_identifier()
  File "/myproject/myproject-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 133, in _create_identifier
    request.headers.get("User-Agent")), 'utf8', errors='replace')
TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported
```

Why is this not happening in dev environment? Hence it must be somehow related to uwsgi on nginx.  Any suggestions? Many Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem won't be solved by downgrading flask alone, because even installing `flask==0.9` would install the latest dependencies, which is the bad `werkzeug==0.9`
Hence you better install the following in this order:

```
pip install werkzeug==0.8.3
pip install flask==0.9
pip install Flask-Login==0.1.3
```

flask login, can then be the latest version 0.1.3. No harm done there.
This stack works for me.

Hope this helps, until the emergency patch is out.

Comment: In my opinion, this is the best thing to do.

Comment: Re: the emergency patch: considering the maintainer of Flask-Login has [said not to expect one](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/issues/78#issuecomment-19428468), I would not expect it to come out. From the looks of it, Flask-Login will not support Flask v0.10 until a cleanup branch. Which, AFAIC, is fine: just don't use Flask 0.10 yet :)

Comment: Also note this is an upstream bug, [reported here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/772). Flask-Login has been updated but cannot address the issue upstream, of course. You may prefer to use the [0.2.x release series](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/tree/0.2.2) now.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me, though I suspect it's Flask-OauthLib that is at issue.

Answer (score 7):

I am having the very same problem on my dev environment, with Flask 0.10 and Flask-Login 0.1.3

looks like flask 0.10 now has unicode request headers so flask-login explodes when trying to encode an already encoded string...

Flask_login people are already working on it:
https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/issues/78

**(EDIT)** instant road to temporary happiness (as seen in github twin thread, thx Kofalt & Kave!)

```
pip uninstall flask ; pip uninstall werkzeug ; pip uninstall Flask-Login ; pip install werkzeug==0.8.3 ; pip install flask==0.9 ; pip install Flask-Login==0.1.3
```

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I have now deleted the entire virtual-env and created a new stack. But I still get the same error:

`Babel==0.9.6
Flask==0.9
Flask-Assets==0.8
Flask-Babel==0.8
Flask-Bcrypt==0.5.2
Flask-Login==0.1.3
Flask-WTF==0.8.3
Jinja2==2.7
MarkupSafe==0.18
WTForms==1.0.4
Werkzeug==0.9
argparse==1.2.1
closure==20121212
cssmin==0.1.4
isodate==0.4.9
jsonschema==2.0.0
py-bcrypt==0.3
pymongo==2.5.2
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz==2013b
rauth==0.5.4
requests==1.1.0
speaklater==1.3
webassets==0.8
wsgiref==0.1.2`

Comment: Same here Kave, maybe werkzeug has to be downgraded too? a emergency fix for flask-login has been requested however.

Comment: Use Flask 0.9 until there is a release or alternatively patch Flask-Login yourself.

Answer (score 2):

My fork which fixes this issue:

```
https://github.com/jgelens/flask-login/tree/0.1.4
```

Install using:

```
pip install https://github.com/jgelens/flask-login/archive/0f07b8fa783c40d09cb284d442a526f067bab28b.zip#egg=flask-login
```

Answer (score 1):

As per losu S., this looks to be a Flask 0.10 problem.  Try to install previous version of Flask in your virtual environment using:

```
pip install Flask==0.9
```

Comment: `pip install Flask==0.9` don't resolve problem because it will download `werkzeug==0.9` so you must use `pip install flask==0.9 werkzeug==0.8.3`